# Coreldraw X7- how to fill an object with black color

Tags: color, corel-draw, fill

I have a image of a church that is outlined, I need to fill the church in with black to burn to a screen, how do I fill the church with the color black in Coreldraw X7?

Answer (score 1):

Select the church, left click on the black colour swatch in the colours palette.

Right click on the "none" swatch to remove the outline.